# SetOnItemLongClickListener in custom cursorAdapter

Tags: android

I can not do function "setOnItemLongClickListener" in my application. Help me please. How I can do it?
I have a pager and pageradapter

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Log.d(Tag,"pager 2");
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Log.d(Tag,"pager 3");
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    Log.d(Tag,"pager 4");
    setListTitle(0);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d(Tag,"ПЕРЕЛИСТНУЛИ СТРАНИЦУ");

            //pager.invalidate();
            setNameList(position);
            //****
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

This is MyFragmentPagerAdapter

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d(Tag, "getItem");
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        MySqlCursorAdapter.prevDate = null;
        Log.d(Tag, "getCount.. получаем количество страниц"+PAGE_COUNT);
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.d(Tag, "getPageTitle");

        return "Title " + position;
    }


    // Код из FragmentPagerAdapter.java

    private String makeFragmentName(int viewId, long id) {
        Log.d(Tag, "makeFragmentName");
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
    }

}
```

PageFragment.java

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Log.d(Tag1, "page="+page);
    test=page;
    PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(Tag1, "FRAGMENT onCreate0");
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    Log.d(Tag1, "FRAGMENT onCreate!!!!!!!!");
    //   dlg1 = new dialog_edit();

}



@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
    case M_EDIT1:

        dlg1.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
        break;
    case M_EDIT2:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Изменение во втором списке", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case M_DELETE:
        //dlg2.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg2");

        break;
    case M_ADD:

        break; 


    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView1");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_fragment, null);
    lvMain_today = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    //tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView2");

    Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView4 id_for_listtsk="+ListTsk.id_for_listtsk);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String id_for_listtsk_today = sdf.format(new Date());
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());    
    //  final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    OnCreateContextMenuListener occm1 = new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AdapterContextMenuInfo aMenuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            itemselected = aMenuInfo.position;
            id_itemselected = (int) aMenuInfo.id;


            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_EDIT1, Menu.NONE, "Изменить1");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Удалить1");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_ADD, Menu.NONE, Integer.toString(id_itemselected));
        }

    };
    Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView3");
    OnCreateContextMenuListener occm2 = new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AdapterContextMenuInfo aMenuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
            itemselected = aMenuInfo.position;
            id_itemselected = (int) aMenuInfo.id;

            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_EDIT2, Menu.NONE, "Изменить2");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Удалить2");
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, M_ADD, Menu.NONE, Integer.toString(id_itemselected));
        }

    };

    //*****************получаем аккаунт**
    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    mSettings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(mSettings.contains(MainActivity.ACCAUNT_NAME)) {
        accauntName=mSettings.getString(MainActivity.ACCAUNT_NAME, "");
        Log.d(Tag, "!!!accauntName = _"+accauntName);
    }

    //пробуем*****
    //  Log.d(Tag, "ПРОВЕРЯЕМ ЛИСТЫ, ЛИСТ = _"+taskList.getId());
    //проверяем если данные в базе
    DBHelper dbHelper_AL = new DBHelper(getActivity());     
    final SQLiteDatabase db1 = dbHelper_AL.getWritableDatabase();
    columns = new String[] { COLUMNLIST_GOOGLEID, COLUMNLIST_ID, COLUMNLIST_TITLE ,COLUMNLIST_ACCAUNT };
    selection = "tasklistAccaunt = ?";
    selectionArgs = new String[] {accauntName};
    //  orderBy = "time_up";
    try {
        c_TL = db1.query("listTable", columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        Log.d(Tag, "смотрим курсор с параметром"+String.valueOf(pageNumber)+" test= "+test+" pagerPos="+MainActivity.pagerPos +" pagecount = "+MainActivity.PAGE_COUNT);
        //тут делаем вилку для листа "все" и остальных
        if (pageNumber ==(MainActivity.PAGE_COUNT - 1)) {
            if (allTasks()) {
                return view;
            }
        }
        String[] arr_date1 = Pager.logCursor(c_TL);
        //идем по курсору
        if (c_TL.moveToFirst()) {
            c_TL.moveToPosition(pageNumber);
            Log.d(Tag, "получаем значение из курсора1");
            nameGoogleId = c_TL.getColumnIndex(COLUMNLIST_GOOGLEID);
            //  titleGoogleId = c_TL.getColumnIndex(COLUMNLIST_TITLE);
            Log.d(Tag, "получаем значение из курсора2 "+nameGoogleId);
            Log.d(Tag, "получаем значение из курсора3");
            listGoogleId = c_TL.getString(nameGoogleId);
            //              listTitle1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listTitle1); //это тут не работает...
            //              listTitle1.setText(c_TL.getString(titleGoogleId));
            //              Log.d(Tag, "listGoogleId="+listGoogleId);

            //              do {
            //                  Log.d(Tag, "получаем значение из курсора3");
            //              listGoogleId = c_TL.getString(nameGoogleId);    
            //              Log.d(Tag, "listGoogleId="+listGoogleId);
            //              }while (c_TL.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    columns = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_ACCAUNT, DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK, DBHelper.COLUMNTASKLIST_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA, DBHelper.COLUMN_STATUS};

    if (listGoogleId != null) {
        selection = "tasklist = ? and data_id = ? and accaunt= ?";
        if (ListTsk.id_for_listtsk==null) {
            selectionArgs = new String[] {listGoogleId, id_for_listtsk_today, accauntName};
        } else {
            selectionArgs = new String[] {listGoogleId, ListTsk.id_for_listtsk, accauntName};
        }
    } else {
        selection = "data_id = ? and accaunt= ?";
        if (ListTsk.id_for_listtsk==null) {
            selectionArgs = new String[] {id_for_listtsk_today, accauntName};
        } else {
            selectionArgs = new String[] {ListTsk.id_for_listtsk, accauntName};
        }
    }


    orderBy = "time_up";
    try {
        c = db1.query("mytable", columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
        //  String[] arr_date = MainActivity.logCursor(c);
        Log.d(Tag, "получаем курсор напрямую..listGoogleTitle = "+listGoogleId+"data_id="+id_for_listtsk_today+"accaunt="+accauntName);
        //  String[] arr_date = logCursor(c);
        //**************************            
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView6");
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);
        int[] listFields = new int[] { R.id.txtTitle, R.id.textData1 };
        String[] dbColumns = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK };
        //      Log.d(Tag, "трассировка" );
        adapter = new MySqlCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.my_list_item,
                c, dbColumns, listFields,
                dbHelper);
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView7");     
        lvMain_today.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView8");
        registerForContextMenu(lvMain_today);
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView9");
        lvMain_today.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(occm1);
        lvMain_today.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {

                Log.d(Tag, "YYYYYYY");
                return false;
           }
        });
        if (c.getCount()==0) {
            Log.d(Tag, "c.getCount()==0");
            c.close();
            db1.close();
            //  db.close(); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView10");




    return view;
}


public static String[] logCursor(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String Tag="States";
    String[] arr_date = new String[c.getCount()];//String[] arr_date  = new String[] {};
    //      Log.d(Tag,"мы в курсоре");
    if (c!=null) {
        Log.d(Tag,"logcursor курсор не нулевой");
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d(Tag,"мы в курсоре1");
            String str;
            int i=-1;
            do {
                Log.d(Tag,"мы в курсоре2");
                str="";
                i=i+1;
                for (String cn: c.getColumnNames()) {
                    str = str.concat(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)));
                }
                Log.d(Tag, "++++"+str);
                arr_date[i]=String.valueOf(str);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        } 
    }
    else {
        Log.d(Tag,"logcursor курсор нулевой");
    }

    return arr_date;

}

private Boolean allTasks() {
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());    
    final SQLiteDatabase db1 = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    columns = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA_INTEGER, DBHelper.COLUMN_ACCAUNT, DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK, DBHelper.COLUMNTASKLIST_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA, DBHelper.COLUMN_STATUS};
    selection = "accaunt= ?";
    selectionArgs = new String[] {accauntName};
    orderBy = "data_id_integer DESC, time_up";
    try {
        c = db1.query("mytable", columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);
        //**************************            
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView6");
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);
        int[] listFields = new int[] { R.id.txtTitle, R.id.textData1 };
        String[] dbColumns = new String[] { DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK };
        //      Log.d(Tag, "трассировка" );
        adapter = new MySqlCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.my_list_item,
                c, dbColumns, listFields,
                dbHelper);
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView7");     
        lvMain_today.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView8");
        registerForContextMenu(lvMain_today);
        Log.d(Tag, "onCreateView9");
    //  lvMain_today.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(occm1);
        if (c.getCount()==0) {
            Log.d(Tag, "c.getCount()==0");
            c.close();
            db1.close();
            //  db.close(); 
        }
        Boolean end = true;
        return end;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Boolean end = false;
        return end;
    }

}
```

And MySQLCursorAdapter

```
public class MySqlCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener {
public MySqlCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, DBHelper dbHelper) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    Log.d(Tag, "создаем mysqlcursoradapter" );
    this.currentCursor = c;
    this.context = context;
    this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
    Log.d(Tag, "MySqlCursorAdapter()");
    Integer b = c.getCount();
    Log.d(Tag, "b="+b);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //-------------------------------------------
    final int viewType = getItemViewType(pos);
    prevDate = null;
    if (currentCursor.getPosition() > 0 && currentCursor.moveToPrevious()) {
    prevDate = currentCursor.getString(currentCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA));
    currentCursor.moveToNext();
}

    Log.d(Tag, "getView() + posss=" + pos);
    View v = inView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);

    }

    this.currentCursor.moveToPosition(pos);

    CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);

    cBox.setTag(Integer.parseInt(this.currentCursor
            .getString(this.currentCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID))));
    //Log.d(Tag, "tag="+cBox.getTag().toString());
    if (this.currentCursor.getString(this.currentCursor
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_STATUS)) != null
            &&  String.valueOf(this.currentCursor
                    .getString(this.currentCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_STATUS))).equals(needsAction)) {
        cBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    cBox.setOnClickListener(this);

    DateTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.DateTitle);
    DateTitle.setText(this.currentCursor.getString(this.currentCursor
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA)));

    //----------------------
    if (prevDate == null || !prevDate.equals(thisDate)) {
        DateTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        DateTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    //------------------------
    txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textData1);
    txtTitle.setText(this.currentCursor.getString(this.currentCursor
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TIME))+" , "+this.currentCursor.getString(this.currentCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
    txtTitle1.setText(this.currentCursor.getString(this.currentCursor
            .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TASK)));
    llText = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llText);
    llText.setTag(Integer.parseInt(this.currentCursor
            .getString(this.currentCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID))));
    llText.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    llText.setOnClickListener(this);



    if (cBox.isChecked())
    {
        Log.d(Tag, " pos444=" + pos);
        txtTitle.setPaintFlags(txtTitle.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);    
        txtTitle1.setPaintFlags(txtTitle1.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(Tag, "!pos5555=" + pos);
        txtTitle.setPaintFlags(txtTitle.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);    
        txtTitle1.setPaintFlags(txtTitle1.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        // txtTitle1.setSelected(true);
    }


    return (v);
}
private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) {
    thisDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATA));
    String thistitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
    Log.d(Tag, "type===="+thisDate+thistitle);

    if (thisDate.equals("1")) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);

    return getItemViewType(cursor);
    }

public void ClearSelections() {
    Log.d(Tag, "ClearSelections()");
    this.dbHelper.clearSelections();
    this.currentCursor.requery();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(Tag, "onClick(View v) в адаптере"+ v.getId());
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.llText:
        Log.d(Tag, "переход в ListTsk activity");
        LinearLayout llText = (LinearLayout) v;
        Integer _idTask = (Integer) llText.getTag();
        Intent intent_add = new Intent(context, AddLineBD.class);
        Log.d(Tag, "_idTask="+_idTask);
        intent_add.putExtra("idTask", _idTask.toString());
        //  intent_add.putExtra("idTitleList", super);
        context.startActivity(intent_add);

        break;  
    case R.id.bcheck:
        if(dbHelper.dbSqlite==null) {
            Log.d(Tag, "00000000000");

            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
            //Log.d(Tag, "onClick");
            CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) v;
            Integer _id = (Integer) cBox.getTag();
            //Integer _id = 4;
            //Log.d(Tag, "Integer _id="+_id.toString());
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            ContentValues valuesListTable = new ContentValues();

            values.put("status", cBox.isChecked() ? "completed" : "needsAction");


            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            calNow.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4:00"));


            Long time_for_date1 = calNow.getTimeInMillis();//-(Integer.valueOf(ValueTZ)*3600000);
            Log.d(CopyOfAsyncLoadTasks.Tag3, "ValueTZ =  "+ValueTZ);
            values.put("data_id_update",time_for_date1);
            valuesListTable.put("tasklistUpdate",time_for_date1);
            try {
                db.update("mytable", values, "_id = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(_id) });
                db.update("listtable", valuesListTable, "tasklistTitle = ?",    new String[] { MainActivity.titleList});
            //  String pp = MainActivity.titleList;
                Log.d(Tag, "checkbox все получилось");
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                Log.d(Tag, "checkbox неудача");
                throw sqle;

            }
        }

        //получаем etag общий листа
        try {
            SharedPreferences mSettingsList;
            mSettingsList = context.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.LIST_ETAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = mSettingsList.edit();
            editor.putString(MainActivity.ETAG, "1");
            editor.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO: handle exception
            //          preferences= intent.getStringExtra("preferences");
            Log.d(Tag, "ни фига не нашли etag общий");//"preferences in intenrservice = "+preferences);
        }
        try {
            MainActivity.update();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        try {
            ListTsk.update();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        break;  

    }


}







@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout llText = (LinearLayout) v;
    Integer ask = (Integer) llText.getTag();

    Log.d(Tag, "длинное!"+ask+"__");

    toggleSelection(ask);
    return true;
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {

    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void toggleSelection(int tag) {

    selectView(tag, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(tag));
}
```

OnLongClick operates in the function of MySqlCursorAdapter. But I need setOnItemLongClickListener. I try do this function in MainActivity

```
ListView lvTareas = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
            lvTareas.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    Log.d(Tag,"pos"+" "+pos);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

But it not work. Help me please? what I do not correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to focusability of `CheckBox` in **my_list_item** layout.

Add below line to root layout of your ListView's Item layout(my_list_item).

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```