# Tap on List Item not responding

Tags: android, android-listview

*why its happening* ? I am doing tap on item but it's **not responding**

whereas i am ***calling another activity***, and also passing some values to that activity

see what my log says:

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(27753): Grow heap (frag case) to 28.932MB for 6554896-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(27753): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 5% free 28662K/29895K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 19ms
D/dalvikvm(27753): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
D/AbsListView(27753): Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/SpannableStringBuilder(27753): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(27753): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 10 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 8 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 9 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 8 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 9 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
D/GestureDetector(27753): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27753): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(27753): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

**Code** to launch activity using tap on any List Item:

```
// selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String emailID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailID)).getText().toString();
                String deviceID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceID)).getText().toString();
                String password = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(LicenseListActivity.this, LicenseCheckActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL_ID, emailID);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DEVICE_ID, deviceID);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PASSWORD, password);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
```

**activity_license.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header" />

     <ListView 
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:divider="#131313"
         android:dividerHeight="3dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/header"
         android:background="@drawable/background"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_license_list.xml:-**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deviceID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailID"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emailID"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/deviceID"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/deviceID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deviceID"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest:-**

```
       <activity 
          android:name="com.m.cam.LicenseCheckActivity" 
          android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        />
```

Comment: some more data is required..post list item xml file..

Comment: try setting focusable and focusable in touch mode to false for all the child elements in the list row, i guess its the image button that takes the focus

Comment: can you show me how ?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by *not responding*? Did it crash? Or, nothing happen at all? Have you debug it step-by-step?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974750/setonitemlongclicklistener-in-custom-cursoradapter/18974927#18974927

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312197/onitemlongclicklistener-is-not-working-in-a-custom-listview/18312410#18312410

Comment: in the manifest file for example for the first textView, add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode:"false"` do the same for all the views and the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh my bad luck, i did silly mistake i was using image button in list item, whereas it was not required so i made change, imagebutton to imageview and issue resolved !

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow" />
```

Comment: Whenever you need to use any focusable view (EditText,Button etc.) use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` as suggested in above links.